# Expression engine 2.1 to 2.11.1 Upgrade never completes

Tags: upgrade, ee2-upgrades

I am trying to do an upgrade from 2.1 to 2.11.1.  I have followed the instructions here https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/installation/update.html.  My issue when i go through the wizard I get to the portion where it is supposed to start the update and it never finishes or errors out.  It just refreshes every 2 seconds but never gets past that.  I let it sit for a couple of hours and never got past that screen.

I then went in to try and get the login page but I get this error.

> Error
>
> Unable to load requested field type file:  ft.rel.php.
>
> Confirm the fieldtype file is located in the
>   expressionengine/third_party/ directory

I noticed a change with the filetype folder where each file type is now in its own folder and also rel went to relationship.  I made sure I copied /system/expressionengine/fieldtypes/relationship/ft.relationship.php and saved it to /system/expressionengine/fieldtypes/ft.rel.php and /system/expressionengine/third_party/ft.rel.php.  This did not make the error go away.

Any advice on what to try next would be appreciated.

Thanks

#### UPDATE

I have gotten past this point now.  I went in and manually changed a couple of things in the database.  First I changed rel to relationship in exp_fieldtypes table.  Second I changed all references to rel to relationship in exp_channel_fields.

I am now able to see the login page but I am not able to login.  I get the following error.

> The following errors were encountered
>
> This form has expired. Please refresh and try again.

I have read some places it could be because of cookies or cache but fixing those did not help at all.  I found the error occurs because of an expired csrf token.  In my case no csrf token.

So again I am stuck as the issue is the upgrade wizard does not do what it is supposed to do.

Wondering if anyone else has had a similar issue with the upgrade wizard from any version of 2 past 2.6 which is where I believe csrf tokens were implemented.  Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue was because the config file was setup to grab a different config file for each environment.  Even though I set it up the same way it causes the upgrade wizard to stall.  Once I copied my dev config file to the base config file the upgrade proceeded as planned.  Then I switched back the base config file to use env specific conf files it worked.